# configuring route in CI to accept n level of url's

Tags: codeigniter, routes

I have a website that is fully dynamic and it creates menu, pages everything from the back-end dynamically.
Now let me show you the sequence of URL being created:

```
http://localhost/occ/level1/level2/....leveln
```

Basically the **level1**, **level2**,... **leveln** are the levels (hierarchy) of a specific menu e.g **home/contact_section/contact_us** now the admin can create multiple pages and also create as much level of menu he wants so what the URL logic is, it will keep on following from parent till the upmost parent and return the URL and at the end of the URL will be the name that I am passing to a generic controller, which basically takes the name run a db query fetches all the data and then displays the page here is my route:

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'Home';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
$route['Admin'] = 'Admin';
//$route['(:any)'] = 'Home/pages/$1';
$route['(:any)/(:any)'] = 'Home/pages/$1/$2';
//$route['(:any)/(:any)'] = 'Home/pages/$1';
```

Now the above route has two issues:

1. Let's suppose I have URL that has two levels  so the route $route['(:any)/(:any)'] = 'Home/pages/$1/$2'; will be called now the pages controller accepts a name and displays the page in my case it is always returning the first name or you can say $1, whereas I want the last name in the URL to be sent to the controller.
2. How can we make it generic? Like I can have n level of names in the URL separated by slash how to configure my route to accepts all URLs with passing the last name of the URL to the controller. Because currently it shows page not found if I have a URL of some other level defined in route!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are using ci 3 you can use [regular expressions](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html?highlight=route#regular-expressions) like

application/config/routes.php

```
//http://localhost/occ/level1/level2/....leveln
$route['(.+)'] = function ( $param ) {
                     $params = implode(",", explode('/', $param));

                     if( $params[0] === 'Admin'){
                         $return = 'Admin/';
                     }
                     else{
                         $return = 'Home/pages/';
                     }

                     return $return . $params;
                 }
```

application/config/Home.php

```
public function pages ( $params ) {
    $str = explode(',', $params);

    //now you can manipulate all params
    $str[0];//param_1
    $str[1];//param_2
    $str[n];//param_n
}
```

Comment: yes i am using C.I 3.X ,i am receiving invalid arguments passed implode()

Comment: change this  `$params = implode(",", $param);` to `$params = ( count($param) > 1) ? implode(",", $param) : $params;`

Comment: yes, i forgot this part before`$params = implode...` add `$param = explode('/', $param);` then `$params = implode(...)`

Comment: hey if you be kind enough to answer one last query eldden! what i want to do is for Admin there is a seperate interface, now all the requests related to Admin/... should be redirected to specific Admin controller Methods but right now it is mixing with the routing we done above